# How to create multiple textboxes as a table inside for loop

Tags: php

This is the code

```
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++)
{

echo "<tr>";
if($sec == 'S+')
{

    for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
    {

        for($td=1;$td<=1;$td++)
        {

           echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk' disabled value='$tr'></td>";

        }
        for($td=2;$td<=$cols;$td++)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk'></td>";

        }


    }
}
else
{
    for($td=1;$td<=1;$td++)
    {

        echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk' value='$tr' readonly></td>";

    }
    for($td=2;$td<=$cols;$td++)
    {

        echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk'></td>";

    }
}

echo "</tr>";
```

}

This is my code but there is only one textbox dynamically here. It only cover entire table, I need to add different textboxes for different column.

Comment: What is the value of your `$cols` variable? 1?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, i`m not sure what you are having porblem with but if u do it like this you can clearly see what structure you are generating:

```
$rows = 5;
$sec = 'S+';
$cols = 5;

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++)
{
  echo "<table style='border: 1px black solid'>";
  echo "<tr>";
    if($sec == 'S+')
    {

      for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
      {

        for($td=1;$td<=1;$td++)
         {

   echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk' disabled value='$tr'></td>";

        }
        for($td=2;$td<=$cols;$td++)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk'></td>";


        }


       }
   }
   else
   {
      for($td=1;$td<=1;$td++)
      {

echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk' value='$tr' readonly></td>";


    }
    for($td=2;$td<=$cols;$td++)
    {

        echo "<td><input type='text' name='bhk'></td>";

    }
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

Just modify inside of IF`s with  to generate any structure u want.